# Envio Automatico de Formulario Con Curl, File_get_contents o Fopen

Tags: php, curl, submit

he visto que en muchos ejemplos que con Curl, File_get_contents o Fopen se puedes enviar o mejor dicho presionar el SUBMIT de un formulario para que este envie el requerimiento. Uso pagina para activar un servicio gratuito de IPTV. Ella requiere que se le presione un Boton para que lea mi IP y con esto poder activar el servicio. Quiero crear un PHP que me automatize esta ejecucion sin tener que ir a la pagina para solo presionar el boton de activacion.

Pagina en Cuestion:https://tv.teleclub.xyz/activar
Stream para Prueba:https://tv.teleclub.xyz/ver/tele?club=CARTOON&format=.m3u8

1er Intento:

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://tv.teleclub.xyz/activar' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://tv.teleclub.xyz' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array( 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ) );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
$postfields = 'submit='.urlencode('Pulsa+aqu%C3%AD+para+activar');
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields );
$page = curl_exec( $ch );
```

2do Intento

```
$postfields = 'submit='.urlencode('Pulsa+aqu%C3%AD+para+activar');

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',     
                     'authority: tv.teleclub.xyz',                   
                     'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1',
                     'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.72 Safari/537.36'
        'content' => $postfields 
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('https://tv.teleclub.xyz/activar', false, $context);
```

3er Intento

```
$postfields = 'submit='.urlencode('Pulsa+aqu%C3%AD+para+activar');
$params = array('http' => array(
    'method' => 'GET',
    'content' => $postfields
));

$ctx = stream_context_create($params);
$sUrl='https://tv.teleclub.xyz/activar';
$fp = @fopen($sUrl, 'rb', false, $ctx);
if (!$fp)
{
    throw new Exception("Problem with $sUrl, $php_errormsg");
}

$response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
if ($response === false) 
{
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $sUrl, $php_errormsg");
}
```

Comment: Si no se está enviando podría ser problema de [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: Intenta capturar los errores y dinos qué muestran.

Comment: Respondiendo a AMBOS 
1) Si no se está enviando podría ser problema de CORS. Verifique el HEADER para ver que UA estaba usando y si es correcto estoy usando el "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.72 Safari/537.36     

2do Generacion de Error LOG le active la Opcion y no me genera ningun error de LOGICA